# Post, Comments, Pages, etc, not showing up in Wordpress Admin

Tags: database, wordpress, admin

I recently moved my WordPress site from one host to another. I cancelled the previous host already because everything displayed just fine on the front end.

However, when I go to Admin Panel, I get a lot of empty pages. The comments, Posts and other pages display a correct count of items at the top, but the actual content is not displayed.

I have disabled all plugins, changed the theme, tried Wordpress Repair, none worked.

Also, some times when I refresh the page, the first item on the list appears, I refresh again, the page goes blank, I refresh again, the page appears but no comments.

The way it works, it almost seems like the script gets terminated while retrieving data.

[Picture of Comments page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbYHI.png)

[Picture of Comments page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgefL.png)

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like pages are not getting rendered due to some error. Kindly change the `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp-config.php` to find them & troubleshoot. Once issues are fixed pages will render properly.